# Is only "void" a non-referenceable type?

Tags: c++, c++11, types

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::boolalpha;
using std::add_rvalue_reference_t;
using std::is_reference_v;


int main(void) {

    cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<int>> << endl;    // true
    cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<int &>> << endl;  // true
    cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<int &&>> << endl; // true
    cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void>> << endl;   // false

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if there are any other types besides void that are non referenceable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::add_rvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/add_reference) won't make reference type for function type with cv-qualifier or ref-qualifier either. e.g.

```
cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void() const>> << endl;   // false
cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void() volatile>> << endl;   // false
cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void() const volatile>> << endl;   // false
cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void() &>> << endl;   // false
cout << boolalpha << is_reference_v<add_rvalue_reference_t<void() &&>> << endl;   // false
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K7nCz6yNwT0HWBt1)